# LCS(longest common subsequence) in Scheme

Tags: scheme, lcs

I try to use Scheme to implement LCS algorithm, but there is a bug.

(define X
  (list #\A #\B #\C #\B #\D #\A #\B))

(define Y
  (list #\B #\D #\C #\A #\B #\A))

(define prefix
  (lambda (i s)
    (if (= i 0)
      '()
      (cons (car s)
            (prefix (- i 1)
                    (cdr s))))))

(define (pick ith s)
  (if (= ith 1)
    (car s)
    (pick (- ith 1)
          (cdr s))))

(define (LCS x y)
  (define (optimal i j)
    (cond ((or (= i 0)
               (= j 0))
           0)
          ((eq? (pick i x)
                (pick j y))
           (+ 1
              (optimal (- i 1)
                       (- j 1))))
          (else (max (LCS (prefix (- i 1) x) y)
                     (LCS x (prefix (- j 1) y))))))
  (optimal (length x)
           (length y)))

> 1 ]=> (load "lcs.scm")
>
> ;Loading "lcs.scm"... done
>   ;Value: lcs
>
> 1 ]=> (lcs X Y)
>
> ;Value: 5

The result should be 4, I do not know where is the bug.

Comment: Split it into smaller parts. Check that each part works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error because your final recursive call in optimal is incorrect.
You are taking the prefix `i-1` for `x` or `j-1` for `y` but what about the other. `j` and `i` might be less than the length of the respective strings, and as such, you are need to prefix the argument accordingly.

The following code works correctly.

```
(define (LCS x y)
  (define (optimal i j)
    (cond
      ((or (= i 0) (= j 0)) 0)
      ((eq? (pick i x) (pick j y)) (+ 1 (optimal (- i 1) (- j 1))))
      (else (max (LCS (prefix (- i 1) x) (prefix j y)) (LCS (prefix i x) (prefix (- j 1) y))))))
  (optimal (length x) (length y)))
```

Note that this problem only exists because you are mixing two different kinds of calls. One that call `LCS` on prefixes and another that calls `optimal` with lesser i and j.
You could replace `LCS` calls with optimal for a simpler solution.

```
(define (LCS x y)
  (define (optimal i j)
    (cond
      ((or (= i 0) (= j 0)) 0)
      ((eq? (pick i x) (pick j y)) (+ 1 (optimal (- i 1) (- j 1))))
      (else (max (optimal (- i 1) j) (optimal i (- j 1))))))
  (optimal (length x) (length y)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your time! I believe I figure it out now!